# Using Moment.js with React Native Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, momentjs

I'm using Moment.js and React Native to display/manipulate date and time in the following fashion but can't quite seem to use it correctly. The code below demonstrates my usage of the library.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

interface event {
  title: string,
  created: any,
  expiration: any
}

const party : event = {
  title: '21st Bday Party',
  created: moment('2019 03 14'),
  expiration: moment('2019 03 15')
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Card>
        <Text>{party.created.format()}</Text>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

I get the following error: **TypeError: moment is not a function.** What am I doing wrong? How can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing moment the wrong way.

You have to import moment like this :

```js
import moment from 'moment';
```

And obviously, don't forget to install the package before :

```js
npm install moment --save
```